# Why does the following use of \parbox not work?

Tags: box, parbox

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\parbox[c][5cm][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth+1\fboxsep\fboxrule}{
  \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
some text
 }%


\end{document}
```

I am getting the error ! Missing number, treated as zero. which is very cryptic. I am just trying to use parbox in a macro to create a fixed box, and reduced the error I am getting to the above (MWE).

Comment: What's the intended width of the `\parbox`? `1\fboxsep\fboxrule` is a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [packages like `framed`, `mdframed`, `tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/topic/boxing)?

Comment: thank you both. I changed +1 to + and added another + before \fboxrule and it worked as I expected (I need to add some spacing to a box so it uses the whole box).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same error you may get if you put a `\fboxrule` alone in the typesetting text. The `\fboxrule` is a control sequence declared by `\dimendef` TeX primitive, so if you put it in the main context, TeX expects that optional `=` is followed, then a number a then a unit. If all is OK, TeX does assignment. For example `\fboxrule=18pt`. But the number isn't here. TeX reports missing number.

Your construction `\dimexpr\linewidth+1\fboxsep\fboxrule` is used in the dimen-reading context. The `\dimenexpr` evaluates `\linewidth+1\fboxsep`. The following `\fboxrule` is out of allowed syntax for `\dimexpr`, so the `\dimexpr` parameter is only `\linewidth+1\fboxsep`. The following `\fboxrule` is read by TeX in main context, no in dimen-reading contex. TeX expects that there will be assignment.